# copying logs in python using the command line function

Tags: python, automation, scp

I had a doubt with my code which i think I can verify here . My requirement is to copy the apache log and error log from two different servers . Iv written down a python program, using a for loop.

My code:

```python
def copylogs(Appache,Errorlog, folder_prefix) :

    root_path = '/home/tza/Desktop/LOGS/'
    folders = ['Appache','Errorlog']
    for folder in folders:


      folder_name = folder_prefix + "_" + folder + str(int(time.time()))
      mkdircmd = "mkdir -p " + root_path + "/" + folder_name
      os.system(mkdircmd)

      filePath = root_path + folder_name
      serverPath = "/var/log/apache/*"

      cmd = "scp " + "symentic@60.62.1.164:" + serverPath + " " + filePath
      cmd = cmd.replace("60.62.1.164" ,myip1)
      cmd = os.system(cmd)
      print "Logs are at:",root_path+folder_name
      time.sleep(10)

      filePath = root_path +  folder
      serverPath = "/var/log/errorlog/*"

      cmd = "scp " + "symentic@10.95.21.129:" + serverPath + " " + filePath
      cmd = cmd.replace("10.95.21.129" ,myip2)
      cmd = os.system(cmd)
      print "Logs are at:",root_path+folder_name
```

now Im calling the function at the end of my program :

```
folder_prefix = "Fail Case-1"
copylogs(Appache,Errorlog, folder_prefix)
```

I have an issue here . Programm executes successfully but the logs get overwritten .what i mean is first Appache folder gets created ,logs are copied and then once again it gets overwritten .

What i require is : create a folder Appachelogs[with the timestamp as defined ] ,copy the logs from machine one  , next copy error logs from machine2 , and continue the program

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `scp` overwrites a target file if it exists. Use different filenames for different servers' logs.

Answer (score 1):

scp by default overwrites if a same file name exists in the target computer.

I would suggest using a combination of a error file name + the timestamp  for naming the error logs. It's always a good convention for logs to have a timestamp in the name and they also prevent the overwriting problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Can u explain this with the above example .It would be easier to understand

Comment: i have added my comment below .

Answer (score 0):

Do your logs have the same filenames on both machines? `scp` will overwrite them if they do.

Personally I would have two directories, one for each machine. Or use a timestamp as suggested by Sylar in his answer.

Comment: So here I currently have a ubuntumachine where im running my scripts and in the scripts whenever there is a return -1 , i just try to copy the logs in the path /home/tza/Desktop/LOGS

Comment: here I use two diff machines one as server and other as client . the server machine is : symentic@60.62.1.164 and the client machine :symentic@10.x.x.x ...  so from the server i would require to copy the appache log and from the client i require to copy error.log   >>>> both to the path : /home/tza/Desktop/LOGS   ..... with this script i am able to achieve this but each time the both the logs get over wriiten ... how do i change this

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `rsync` instead of `scp`